# Possibility of installing two versions of Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, installation, apk

Few days ago I tried to install two version of Google Play Store simultaneously. I used APKTool in order to change package name (it's a standard procedure for this purpose). I aligned and signed new apk and I managed to install it. But modyfied Google Play Store gets stopped (standard error, Google Play Store has been stopped) when I'm trying to execute Store. My question is how to have two Google Play Stores installed simultaneously? Of course if it's possible at all.

Comment: It's for educational purposes. I tried this with other apps and it's worked so I want to try with "something harder". As far as I know it's not illegal because I don't distribute modified app.

Comment: Okay. Personally I also through that Google won't let me cheating it's own app.